# ASP.NET - How to add variable in string

Tags: asp.net, .net, variables

I want to add variable in string.

**This is my code**

btnAddHelp.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Are you sure to navigate__**variable**__ to other page?');");

**my problem is with apostrophes**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few approaches here, all of which are varying forms of string concatenation.

**The Concatenation Operator `+`**

The most basic approach would be to simply break your initial string and add your variable in.

```
var script = "return confirm('Are you sure to navigate " + __variable__ + " to other page?');";
btnAddHelp.Attributes.Add("onclick", script);
```

**The [`String.Format()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) Method**

The `String.Format()` method can be helpful in allowing you to pass in your variable as a parameter to your string (it will replace the placeholder elements `{0}` based on the index of the parameter that was passed in). This can be useful if you are reusing variables within the same string as well.

```
var script = String.Format("return confirm('Are you sure to navigate {0} to other page?');",__variable__);
btnAddHelp.Attributes.Add("onclick", script);
```

**[String Interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) (Available in C# 6+)**

C# 6 introduced a more elegant alternative to the `String.Format()` method that allows you to inject the variable that you want to use directly into a specific position in the string using `{}` brackets.

```
var script = $"return confirm('Are you sure to navigate {__variable__} to other page?');"
btnAddHelp.Attributes.Add("onclick", script);
```

**Regarding Your Variable**

You mentioned that you were encountering issues with regards to quotes. These can typically be handled within any of the above recommendations, however if the quotes are present within your variable, then you may need to elaborate a bit more about it (i.e. Is it a string? What does it look like?, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Simple concatenation.  Not sure what the issue is?

```
btnAddHelp.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Are you sure to navigate " + __variable__ + " to other page?');");
```

Or you can use String.Format

```
String myString = String.Format("return confirm('Are you sure to navigate {0} to other page?');",__variable__);

btnAddHelp.Attributes.Add(myString);
```

Answer (score 1):

another solution with string formatting and javascript escaping:

```
btnAddHelp.Attributes.Add("onclick", string.Format("return confirm('Are you sure to navigate{0} to other page?');", HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(your_variable_here)));
```